# How to Implement Concepts in C++17

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, sfinae, c++-concepts

I found this great article on how to implement [Concepts in C++14](https://www.foonathan.net/2016/09/cpp14-concepts/). In one section about how to make a `compiles` checker he gives the following:

```cpp
template <typename ... Ts>
using void_t = void;

template <typename T, template <typename> class Expression, typename AlwaysVoid = void_t<>>
struct compiles : std::false_type {};

template <typename T, template <typename> class Expression>
struct compiles<T, Expression, void_t<Expression<T>>> : std::true_type {};
```

The above code will check if an expression compiles, but has no checks on the return type. Later on he mentioned that a `compiles_convertible_type` and `compiles_same_type` checker can be created by wrapping the `compiles` trait but doesn't give an example of how to do that, stating that it is simple. However, I am somewhat new to SFINAE so I'm not sure exactly what to do here.

```cpp
template <typename T, typename Result, template <typename> class Expression>
struct compiles_convertible_type : /* some invocation of compiles<> trait here */

template <typename T, typename Result, template <typename> class Expression>
struct compiles_same_type : /* some invocation of compiles<> trait here */
```

For reference, this is what I have tried, but it returns true for everything. I think because the `is_same` and `is_convertible` expressions compile.

```cpp
template <typename T, typename Result, template <typename> class Expression>
struct compiles_convertible_type :
    compiles<T, Expression, void_t<std::is_convertible<Result, std::result_of<Expression<T>>>>> {};

template <typename T, typename Result, template <typename> class Expression>
struct compiles_same_type :
    compiles<T, Expression, void_t<std::is_same<Result, std::result_of<Expression<T>>>>> {};

namespace memory {
struct memory_block{};
}

struct MyAllocator {
    memory::memory_block allocate_block(){return {};};
    void         deallocate_block(memory::memory_block){};
    std::size_t  next_block_size() const {return 0;};
};

struct MyBadAllocator {
    memory::memory_block allocate_block(){return {};};
    void         deallocate_block(memory::memory_block){};
    void  next_block_size() const {};
};

template <typename T>
struct BlockAllocator_impl
{
    template <class Allocator>
    using allocate_block = decltype(std::declval<Allocator>().allocate_block());

    template <class Allocator>
    using deallocate_block = decltype(std::declval<Allocator>().deallocate_block(std::declval<memory::memory_block>()));

    template <class Allocator>
    using next_block_size = decltype(std::declval<const Allocator>().next_block_size());

    using result = std::conjunction<
        compiles_convertible_type<T, memory::memory_block, allocate_block>,
        compiles<T, deallocate_block>,
        compiles_same_type<T, std::size_t, next_block_size>
        >;

    using has_allocate_block = compiles_convertible_type<T, memory::memory_block, allocate_block>;
    using has_deallocate_block = compiles<T, deallocate_block>;
    using has_next_block_size = compiles_same_type<T, std::size_t, next_block_size>;
};

template <typename T>
using BlockAllocator = typename BlockAllocator_impl<T>::result;
template <typename T>
using BlockAllocatorAllocate = typename BlockAllocator_impl<T>::has_allocate_block;
template <typename T>
using BlockAllocatorDeallocate = typename BlockAllocator_impl<T>::has_deallocate_block;
template <typename T>
using BlockAllocatorNextBlockSize = typename BlockAllocator_impl<T>::has_next_block_size;

#include <fmt/core.h>

int main()
{
    fmt::print("MyBadAllocator\n");
    fmt::print("has allocate: {}\n", BlockAllocatorAllocate<MyBadAllocator>::value);
    fmt::print("has deallocate: {}\n", BlockAllocatorDeallocate<MyBadAllocator>::value);
    fmt::print("has next block size: {}\n", BlockAllocatorNextBlockSize<MyBadAllocator>::value);
    fmt::print("Is BlockAllocator: {}\n", BlockAllocator<MyBadAllocator>::value);
    fmt::print("MyAllocator\n");
    fmt::print("has allocate: {}\n", BlockAllocatorAllocate<MyAllocator>::value);
    fmt::print("has deallocate: {}\n", BlockAllocatorDeallocate<MyAllocator>::value);
    fmt::print("has next block size: {}\n", BlockAllocatorNextBlockSize<MyAllocator>::value);
    fmt::print("Is BlockAllocator: {}\n", BlockAllocator<MyAllocator>::value);
}
```

output:

```
MyBadAllocator
has allocate: true
has deallocate: true
has next block size: true // expect false
Is BlockAllocator: true   // expect false
MyAllocator
has allocate: true
has deallocate: true
has next block size: true
Is BlockAllocator: true
```

Comment: can you not enable c++20 and use the official std implementation?

Comment: I am in an embedded environment and unable to upgrade to a compiler which supports C++20.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following implementations give exactly the expected output (and probably those are close to what the author of the article used behind the scenes):

```
template <typename T, typename Result, template <typename> class Expression, typename AlwaysVoid = void_t<>>
struct compiles_same_type : std::false_type {};

template <typename T, typename Result, template <typename> class Expression>
struct compiles_same_type<T, Result, Expression, void_t<Expression<T>>> : std::is_same<Result, Expression<T>> {};

template <typename T, typename Result, template <typename> class Expression, typename AlwaysVoid = void_t<>>
struct compiles_convertible_type : std::false_type {};

template <typename T, typename Result, template <typename> class Expression>
struct compiles_convertible_type<T, Result, Expression, void_t<Expression<T>>> : std::is_convertible<Result, Expression<T>> {};
```

The trick is to replace the inherited `std::true_type` on the template specialization selected by SFINAE when the expression is valid with other struct/class that does the desired type check (aka a type trait in C++'s standard library terminology). Of course you should modify the template parameter list of the initial `compiles` type with the extra parameters needed by the inherited type trait (in those cases only `Result` is needed as both `std::is_same` and `std::is_convertible` have only two template type parameters).

In addition, the `std::result_of` is both unnecessary and wrong. `std::is_same` will check if the value of `Result` type parameter is something staring with `std::result_of` rather than the actual type of the expression. You probably would want something like `std::result_of<...>::type`, but that will be an invalid as `Expression<T>` is not a callable type in any usage from the BlockAllocator example. You should keep in mind that the actual value of `Expression` is already the resulted type and not the expression itself:

```
template <class Allocator>
using allocate_block = decltype(std::declval<Allocator>().allocate_block());
```

you should interpret that as "the resulted type of the expression `a.allocate_block()` where `a` has `Allocator` type.

If you want to see more information about `std::result_of` then cppreference is a good place to start: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/result_of